# SharePoint WSS 3.0 - Fastest approach to build data-bound forms?

Tags: sharepoint, webforms, wss, dataviewwebpart

Pardon the vague question, but I've just inherited a project to build a couple dozen forms pulling data from a SQL 2005 database. The forms are mostly standard database lookups with just a couple updates so the data layer is very simple -- I'm the DBA -- but we just recently started using SharePoint WSS 3.0 for a departmental web site and I would prefer to integrate these forms into WSS rather than build a separate standalone ASP.NET app.

I'm hoping there is some RAD framework out there that integrates with WSS for data bound forms. I've been searching online, but haven't found anything very promising and the data viewer web part in SharePoint Designer looks complicated to integrate with an external SQL database.

TIA,
Rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there isn't any real integration with SharePoint happening, the easiest option is probably to build the forms as standard .net user controls then add them to SharePoint using SmartPart.